# Can I justify that the Electric Field intensity will double for the case described using the following relativistic and quantum mechanic argument?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity

If one is heading towards the source of a constant amplitude EM wave at a speed that makes the frequency twice that of another observer, then the amplitude of the E (electric field amplitude) will double relative to the other observer. The power will be 4 times as great relative to the other observer, since power is proportional to ExB according to Poynting's theorem, B (magnetic field amplitude) being doubled as well. Four times the power makes sense since there are twice as many photons per time (assuming no change in photons per cycle), and each photon is doubled in frequency, and thus double in energy per photon E = hf (Planck's constant times frequency). Please correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: Sounds about right. What exactly is the question?